# Is there a way to get the Column menu updates automatically with the sheet menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am devoloping an app where the user upload his excel file and gets the Sheets and columns. How do I get the Columns drop-down menu (The second one) to update with the Sheets drop-down menu(First one).

I have already tried to make a function 'Update' that gets the new sheet form the Fuction 'GetSheet' and update it. But it does not work as the column drop-down menu get Always stucked in the Default sheet.

```
master.title('ATT Analytics App')
master.geometry("400x250")

Myfile= filedialog.askopenfile()
wb = load_workbook(filename = str(Myfile.name))
#Sheets = wb.sheetnames


variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(str(wb.sheetnames[2])) # default value
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, str(wb.sheetnames[0]), str(wb.sheetnames[1]), str(wb.sheetnames[2]), str(wb.sheetnames[3]))
w.pack()



def GetSheet():
    FileRead = pd.read_excel(str(Myfile.name),sheet_name= str(variable.get())) 
    MyHeadres = list(FileRead.columns.values)
    return MyHeadres, FileRead

variable1 = StringVar(master)

def Update(TheHeaders):
    variable1.set(str(TheHeaders[0]))
    wc = OptionMenu(master, variable1, str(TheHeaders[0]), str(TheHeaders[1]), str(TheHeaders[2]), str(TheHeaders[3]), str(TheHeaders[4]), str(TheHeaders[5]))
    return wc

def RunAll():
    GetMySheet, FileRead = GetSheet()
    UpdateMysheet = Update(GetMySheet)
    return UpdateMysheet, variable1.get(), FileRead 

button = Button(master, text="Run", command=RunAll)
button.pack(side = TOP)

UpdateMysheet, MyColumn, ReadMyFile = RunAll()
UpdateMysheet.pack()
FileRead = ReadMyFile

mainloop()
```

I want to bring my Code to be able to update the Column Drop-down (Variable1) menu with the drop down menu (Variable), which works fine and also get to store the column you want and move on the choose another one and so on..
I would appreciate your help a lot.

Edit: Now when I choose another sheet, the Default value of the columns updates to the new sheet, but when I look the complete List, I find out that the values are from the old sheet.

Comment: Add `command=Update` to `menu(First one)` to set `menu (The second one)`

Comment: example how to [update second OptionMenu when you select in first OptionMenu](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/optionmenu/two%20optionmenu%20connected/main.py)

Comment: @furas the solution you provided me is based on an If-Statement that needs defined value, in my Situation that did not work for me or at least I could not modify it to work me, Thanks very much though.

Comment: @stovfl Your Suggestion got me to update the Default value but not list as a whole but definitly put in the right path thanks very very much.

Comment: you don't have to use if-statements if you don't need them. Example shows how to use two OptionMenu together. In example more important is how to use `command=` to change items in second OptionMenu after you select element in first OptionMenu - but you can change items using any method, it doesn't have to be  If-Statement

Comment: @furas Thanks very much, I'll try it once again, I did not yet get the results that I want.

Comment: @A.Yas: Your problem is in `def Update`, you create a new `tk.OptionMenu` instead of update the data and **don't** `.destroy()` the previos one. **Second**, you don't  **layout** the new created `OptionMenu`.

Comment: @stovfl, could you please, modify and post the Code, that you think works, thanks for your time.